# Is `sigmoid` required for binary cross entropy?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

I have a DNN that has to predict whether an input belongs to a class or not. During training, I use `binary cross entropy` as a loss function. I noticed that if my output neuron has a `relu` activation then the back propagation doesn't actually work. But when I switch to `sigmoid` it starts working and I notice the loss drops with epochs (and batches) to reasonable amounts.
Is this caused by the way the loss is calculated? E.g. it matters whether the output is `0` or `-1`?

Answer (score 3):

"ReLu" gives out a real no. output >=0, using a binary cross-entropy  doesn't make any sense here. Actually using a "ReLu" in output layer for classification won't be any helpful. 
Binary cross-entropy calculates loss for the function function which gives out binary output, here "ReLu" doesn't seem to do so. For "Sigmoid" function output is [0,1], for binary classification we check if output >0.5 then class 1, else 0.
This clearly follows the concept of using binary cross entropy as the out is only two values that is binary.
"ReLu" must be used where we need to get out in term of real values such as regression.
 and for that loss function will be squared sum of error.